# Reset Array back to Original values

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, reset

I'm working on a simple game with Javascript, involving changes to an HTML5 canvas. Have a number (10+) of objects entered in an array:

```
var boxes = [];
    boxes.push({
        x: 0,
        y:canvas.height - 370,
        width: 400,
        height: 20});
    boxes.push({
        x: 300,
        y:canvas.height - 100,
        width: 150,
        height: 90});
```

The entire array is then run through an update function, which changes the x value depending on the player's position:

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                if (boxes[1].x > -3000 + canvas.width) {
                    boxes[i].x -= robot.speed * modifier;
                    robot.x = canvas.width - 300;
                }; 
            };
```

When the player dies a reset function is run:

```
var reset = function () {
            robot.x = 0;
            robot.y = 500;
            ++deaths;
            };
```

I'm looking for a way to reset all the values of the `boxes` array to the original values when this function runs, essentially resetting the map, without having to enter each one manually, ie `boxes[1].x = 300`

https://jsfiddle.net/to31b612/

Comment: how about you make a copy of the original array (i.e. a backup) right after initializing it with values and when player dies, then you copy it back from the backup? is that an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply initialize from a single function:

```
var boxes;
initBoxes();

function initBoxes() {
    boxes = [];
    boxes.push({
        x: 0,
        y:canvas.height - 370,
        width: 400,
        height: 20});
    boxes.push({
        x: 300,
        y:canvas.height - 100,
        width: 150,
        height: 90});
}
```

Then just recall `initBoxes()` every time you need to initialize it.

Comment: This worked great, I just had to change the format of a second array to something similar and run it through the reset function at the same time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just initialize boxes inside the `reset()` function, and make sure to call call `reset()` before the first run of the game, too.

```
var deaths = -1;
var boxes = [];

function reset() {
    robot.x = 0;
    robot.y = 500;
    boxes = [{
        x: 0,
        y:canvas.height - 370,
        width: 400,
        height: 20
    }, {
        x: 300,
        y:canvas.height - 100,
        width: 150,
        height: 90
    }];
    ++deaths;
}
```

Comment: This actually didn't quite work, at least not with a simple cut/paste. The x values were shifted by 300px but I think it was because of how other pieces of the code were using the values, otherwise it looked like it would work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the [Memento Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/memento-design-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

just use 2 variables

```
var initBoxes = [];
initBoxes.push({
    x: 0,
    y:canvas.height - 370,
    width: 400,
    height: 20});
initBoxes.push({
    x: 300,
    y:canvas.height - 100,
    width: 150,
    height: 90});

var boxes = initBoxes;
```

Then when ever you need to reset boxes just

```
boxes = initBoxes;
```